# Is an ARIMA(0,0,0) with non-zero mean equivalent to white noise?

Tags: time-series, arima, white-noise

Is an ARIMA with a non-zero mean equivalent to white noise? If not, how should the mean be interpreted?

Comment: Hi: Suppose in a fictitious world there was some guarantee that the interest rate on a stock, $X_t$, per day was 10 basis points continuosly compounded. Then, a model for the log price of that stock could be $log(P_t) = log(P_{t-1}) + .0010 + \epsilon_t$. The error term $\epsilon_t$ can still be thought of as an approximation to white noise. Arima-wise, the price difference could be thought of as ARIMA(0,0,0) with non-zero mean.

Comment: ok! But is the price difference not an Arima(0,1,0) then? And it still does not answer if an Arima(0,0,0) with non-zero mean is white noise. Or am I missing something in your answer?

Comment: Isn't part of your [definition of white noise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_noise#Mathematical_definitions) that its mean be *zero*?  If not, then you're using an unusual definition that you need to disclose if we're to be of much help.

Comment: @endorphinus: the link that whuber points to say that white noise requires a zero mean so, technically speaking, it can't be true. thanks to whuber for that knowledge. but, no, in the model I described, the log price difference is arima(0,0,0). the log price is arima(0,1,0).

Comment: Note that white noise from a theoretical perspective is the derivative of brownian motion which doesn't exist. It's a fictitous concept but from a modelling standppoint we think of the normal(0,1) error terms as "white noise". but they're really not. white noise really is $dw/dt$ where w is brownian motion.

Comment: Thanks! @whuber, how should the model be interpreted then?

Comment: The mean is the expected value of each observation and all observations are uncorrelated.  The best forecast of any future value is the mean.

Comment: @whuber Thanks!